# Syncing Calendar Events

Tags: tasks

In my company Whenever a user creates an events for a different user, he/she can see in his/her outlook calendar as we are using 365. I have checked they are not using Salesforce for Outlook, Lightning sync, Lightning for Outlook or any other Salesforce feature to sync.

Now I need to find out which app is responsible for this syncing. Please suggest me how and where I should go in salesforce to determine the same. They are not using auth provider either.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Can you check if there are any installed packages on your org which does this?

Comment: I have checked the installed package, I thought one of them (Activity Hub ) might be invloved in this but I don't know how to ensure that this is the app which is responsible in syncing the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

activity hub is the installed package which is syncing salesforce with outlook calendar.Please find below screenshot from the app exchange
[Activity Hub on App exhange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000pvcMEAQ)

[image]